# How do I get URLs that are being accessed in my browser in 'real time'?

Tags: python, google-chrome, url, browser, wireshark

I want to write a program that returns the current or last visited URL by me on my computer (Windows 10) browser. Is there any way in which I can get that URL?

I tried using Python and SQLite to access Chrome history database on C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History and it worked, but if I'm using the browser, the database gets locked.

I know that by using Wireshark, one can see the packets when accessing an URL, but I cannot find the complete URL in those packets fields, only the server name (ie: stackoverflow.com).

I'd like to know whether there is a way in which I can see that information as it's done by Wireshark, but only to get the complete URL, nothing else. Thank you!

Comment: The visited path would be part of the HTTP header. You could inspect that in Wireshark. You could get this programmatically by using `scapy` and examining the headers that way.

Comment: Note that that only works for HTTP requests, as HTTPS would be encrypted.

Comment: Correct @SuperStormer, I'm particularly speaking about HTTPS requests since those seem to be the most common today. Do you know whether there is a way in which I could decrypt that path from those packets? Since the program would run on my computer, I think I should be able to decrypt that content in some way, but I'm not sure how.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by using mitmproxy: https://mitmproxy.org/. This video on YouTube helped me with the installation and setup process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BXsaU42yok. The video explains the installation on Mac, but it's not so different from Windows. Then you can use Python to capture and process the URLs contained within the HTTPS requests by using the flow.request.pretty_url property: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-scripting/.